# How to exit threads in python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

How  to exit 2 threads I create using python code? I'm trying to end the program when I type "break" but it doesn't work for me here.

```
import socket
import threading
import time

IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 25565

server_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_sock.bind((IP, PORT))
server_sock.listen()
conn, addr = server_sock.accept()

def recv():
    while True:
        income_message = conn.recv(1024)
        print("client: " + income_message.decode())

def send():
    while True:
        message =input("")
        conn.send(message.encode())
        if message == "break":
            break

def main():
    x = threading.Thread(target=recv, args=())
    x.start()
    y = threading.Thread(target=send, args=())
    y.start()

    print("started threads!")
    if not send():
        x.join()
        y.join()
        server_sock.close()
        print("stop")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I thought it will end the program when I type "break" but it still running.

Comment: `recv` does not have an end.

Comment: `if income_message.decode() == "break": break`

Comment: Why not just close the socket so the recv thread throws an error? That's the lazy way :)

Comment: create your recieve thread with the argument daemon=True.  this will cause that thread to end when  your program ends.  x = threading.Thread(target=recv, daemon=True)